# how long ago the given time was compared to now

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular directive/filter/service for formatting date so that it displays how long ago the given time was compared to now

i have to display the time difference from the current time in angularjs .

```
created time 2015-09-01T10:59:00.568Z

current time 2015-09-01T11:00:00.568Z.
```

can anyone know how to display 1 min ago in a chat application window.

Comment: Have a look at http://momentjs.com. It is a great library for doing things like this.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using a **'filter'** to do your formatting. In the template you just apply the filter in your expression as in the following [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/W0EmOPmqpO7Yi5evAlp2?p=preview) I made.

Here's the **HTML**:

```
{{currentdate - prevdate | formatDiff}} mins ago}}
```

And here's your **filter**:

```
app.filter('formatDiff', function() {
  return function(items) {
    minutes = items/60000;
    return Math.round(minutes)
  }
})
```

Subsequently, if you want to display hours, days etc. you can tweak the code in your filter accordingly.

Comment: Your welcome, please mark any answer correct if it was the best answer according to you.

Comment: you posted the correct anser based on my question but here i need to display initially : less than a minute ago
after 1 min :about a minute ago
after 1 hour : about 1 hours ago that can be possible with the below answer